# Android: Issue creating Custom 3 state toggle button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I'm trying to create a 3 state toggle button by overriding the `Button` class.

Although, there is no error in the code, but Eclipse is showing following issue in layout xml.

The following classes could not be instantiated:

```
- com.example.threewaytoggle.TriToggleButton (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.
Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code when shown in Eclipse
```

And in the error log, this is coming:

```
com.example.threewaytoggle.TriToggleButton failed to instantiate.

java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.view.View.mergeDrawableStates(View.java:7506)
at com.example.threewaytoggle.TriToggleButton.onCreateDrawableState(TriToggleButton.java:42)
at android.view.View.getDrawableState(View.java:7410)
at android.view.View.setBackgroundDrawable(View.java:7583)....
```

Following is the code:
**Layout xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.example.threewaytoggle.TriToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/triToggleButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TriToggleButton" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Custom Button Class:**

```
package com.example.threewaytoggle;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.Button;

public class TriToggleButton extends Button {

    int _state = 0;
    public TriToggleButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        _state = 0;
        this.setText("1");
    }

    public TriToggleButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        _state = 0;
        this.setText("1");
    }

    public TriToggleButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        _state = 0;
        this.setText("1");
    }

    private final int[] STATE_ONE_SET = { R.attr.state_one };
    private final int[] STATE_TWO_SET = { R.attr.state_two };
    private final int[] STATE_THREE_SET = { R.attr.state_three };

    @Override
    protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
        final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 3);

        if (_state == 0) {
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, STATE_ONE_SET);
        } else if (_state == 1) {
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, STATE_TWO_SET);
        } else if (_state == 2) {
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, STATE_THREE_SET);
        }

        return drawableState;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        nextState();
        return super.performClick();
    }

    private void nextState() {
        _state++;
        if (_state > 2) {
            _state = 0;
        }
        setButtonText();
    }

    private void setButtonText() {
        //TODO      
    }

    public int getState() {
        return _state;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious of how the attr.xml and drawable xml look like.

Comment: You can do modulo instead of ++ and bounds check.

Comment: Also, I used enum instead of integer. This enables me to save the arrays as part of the enums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it....Only static was missing in:

```
private static final int[] STATE_ONE_SET = { R.attr.state_one };
private static final int[] STATE_TWO_SET = { R.attr.state_two };
private static final int[] STATE_THREE_SET = { R.attr.state_three };
```

But how come this creates a problem...?

Comment: Answering your question: this creates a problem because `onCreateDrawableState` is invoked within the parent's constructor. This means that your object's constructor haven't yet finished, so the arrays haven't been initialized when they aren't static.